# Trying to store a radio button selection on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to store a radio button selection on a user poll (Yes or No) on a html page using Jquery and local storage, but it won't work and just keeps reverting to no selection on refresh.

HTML

```
     <label><input type="radio" name="selector" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="selector" value="No">No</label>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("input[type=radio]").on('click', function(){
            localStorage.setItem("pollselected", value);
    });
    var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("pollselected");
    if (storedValue !== null) {
        $("input[value=\""+storedValue+"\"]").click();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: `value` is undefined....try `this.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` is what you needed in short terms. You needed a way to identify what radio buttons were clicked. I added the `id="yes"` and the `id="no"`. To make it not store an `object` in the storage, instead it stores yes or no as the selection. Then we can just grab the yes or no radio button. I tested this example locally for you.

> Example: Local Storage Blocked

```js
function test(){
    var test = 'test';
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(test, test);
        localStorage.removeItem(test);
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}

 
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (test() === true) { // Available
        $(function() {
            $("input[type=radio]").on('click', function() {
                let choice = $(this).attr('id'); // Get this id
                localStorage.setItem("pollselected", choice); // Store
            });

            var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("pollselected");
            if (storedValue !== null) {
                console.log(storedValue) // yes or no
                $("#" + storedValue).click(); // We could make this simpiler if we stored #yes or #no
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert('No local storage')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="selector" id="no" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="selector" id="yes" value="No">No</label>
```

Comment: Just tried this, it didn't work. Still resets on page reload.

Comment: Make sure your using a browser that support local storage. Example works.

Comment: I usually use Brave but just to make sure I checked with Microsoft Edge, still doesn't work.

Comment: Local Storage didn't work for IE9, so I imagine that this is still the case in MS Edge. Copy and paste my code, and run in chrome. I put a test to check if local storage is valid.

Comment: It works on chrome as you said. Cheers for the help!